# Exercise - find a passcode using dimensional arrays and function

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I´m stuck on this:

Write a function named getValidPassword that takes a two dimensional array as parameter.

Each entry in the first array represents a passcode. You need to find the passcode that has no odd digits and returns that passcode from your function.
Here’s an example:

```
var loggedPasscodes =[
[1, 4, 4, 1],
[1, 2, 3, 1],
[2, 6, 0, 8],
[5, 5, 5, 5],
[4, 3, 4, 3]
];
getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) // returns the array: [2, 6, 0, 8]
```

Tried this way, but error message shows: >>>>Code is incorrect Function getValidPassword is not working as requested." [2,6,0,8].

```
`var loggedPasscodes=[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
[1, 2, 3, 1],
[2, 6, 0, 8],
[5, 5, 5, 5],
[4, 3, 4, 3],
];
var getValidPassword = function(getPassword){
var passcode = [];
var cache = [];
for (var i = 0; i < getPassword.length; i++){
for (var j = 0; j < getPassword[i].length; j++){
if(getPassword[i][j] % 2 === 0){           cache.push(getPassword[i][j]);
}
else {break;
}
if(getPassword[i].length === cache.length){
passcode= cache.slice();
}
}
}
return passcode;
};
console.log('[' + getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) + ('') + ']');`
```

Also this:

```
function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
    return loggedPasscodes.filter(passcode => passcode.every(n => n % 2 === 0));
};

let loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [10, 2, 4, 42],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes));
and


function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
    for (let i = 0; loggedPasscodes.length > i; i++) {
        let passcode = loggedPasscodes[i];
        let temImpar = false;
        for (let j = 0; passcode.length > j; j++) {
            if (passcode[j] % 2 !== 0)  { // ímpar
                temImpar = true;
                 números)
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! temImpar) {
            return passcode; 
    }
};



 let loggedPasscodes =[
        [1, 4, 4, 1],
        [1, 2, 3, 1],
        [2, 6, 0, 8],
        [5, 5, 5, 5],
        [4, 3, 4, 3]
    ];
    
    console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes)); // [2, 6, 0, 8
```

]

Also this:

```
function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
let codes = [];
for (let i = 0; loggedPasscodes.length > i; i++) {
    let passcode = loggedPasscodes[i];
    let temImpar = false;
    for (let j = 0; passcode.length > j; j++) {
        if (passcode[j] % 2 !== 0)  { // ímpar
            temImpar = true;
           
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! temImpar) {
        codes.push(passcode); 
    }
}
return codes;
};

let loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes))
```

This  one:

```
function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
    return loggedPasscodes.find(passcode => passcode.every(n => n % 2 === 0));
};

let loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes)); // [2, 6, 0, 8]
```

Also try to replicate something like this example:

```
function retornaNNumerosPares(n) {
let numerosPares = [];
for (let i = 0; numerosPares.length < n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        numerosPares.push(i);
    }
}
return numerosPares;
```

}

```
console.log(retornaNNumerosPares(5));
```

But none of the above are working. Can you please help me, I´m almost finnished all the exercices.

Can you please help?

Comment: the first one is working, as well the shortest one. what is the question?

Comment: Question is "Write a function named getValidPassword that takes a two dimensional array as parameter.

Each entry in the first array represents a passcode. You need to find the passcode that has no odd digits and returns that passcode from your function. Here’s an example:

var loggedPasscodes =[
[1, 4, 4, 1],
[1, 2, 3, 1],
[2, 6, 0, 8],
[5, 5, 5, 5],
[4, 3, 4, 3]
];
getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) // returns the array: [2, 6, 0, 8]

Comment: yes, but your code works. maybe it is a problem by creating a new array instead of taking one of the given array, who knows,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast approach takes every chance to end an unnecessary loop.

This approach iterate the array of codes and iterates the code as well by check unwanted numbers, then perform a continue of the outer loop, otherwise return the found array at the end of the inner loop.

```js
const
    getValidPassword = codes => {
        outer: for (const code of codes) {
            for (const value of code) if (value % 2) continue outer;
            return code;
        }
    },
    loggedPasscodes = [[1, 4, 4, 1], [1, 2, 3, 1], [2, 6, 0, 8], [5, 5, 5, 5], [4, 3, 4, 3]];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes));
```

Comment: This one worked finally! Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by checking the first value of each array to knock out the uninteresting values. Any matches do my second loop and upon any detection it's even cancel out.

If a complete match is made you'd then return the result as show in comment or push it and continue finding more codes.

```js
let loggedPasscodes = [
  [1, 4, 4, 1],
  [1, 2, 3, 1],
  [2, 6, 0, 8],
  [5, 5, 5, 5],
  [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
  let Codes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < loggedPasscodes.length; i++) {
    console.log("Read Array:", i);
    if (loggedPasscodes[i][0] % 2 == 0) { // Check if first value is even
      let GoodCode = true;
      for (let x = 1; x < 4; x++) { // Let's fast check the array now
        if (loggedPasscodes[i][x] % 2 != 0) {
          GoodCode = false;
          break; // Break if it's a waste of time (odds)
        }
      }
      //if (GoodCode == true) Codes.push(loggedPasscodes[i]); // Build our array if there's more codes even.
      if (GoodCode == true) return loggedPasscodes[i];
    }
  }
  return Codes;
};
console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes)); // [2, 6, 0, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was tough but I finally got it accepted, even though I had the same solution with many other versions.

Nevertheless I like Nina Scholz version better for being really really short and elegant.

Here's my working code:

```js
var getValidPassword = function(pass) {
    var buffer = [];
    var evenArrays = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < pass[i].length; j++) {
            // Testing if cell is odd or even
            if (pass[i][j]%2 !== 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                buffer.push(pass[i][j]);
            }
        }
        // Before changing line pass buffer to the evenArray if buffer is complete
        if(pass[i].length === buffer.length) {
            evenArrays = buffer;
        }
        buffer=[];
    }
    return evenArrays;
};

var loggedPasscodes = [
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were expected to return the array, but you returned a copy of the array instead.  When comparing two arrays directly, Java only compares the memory address.

```
int[] a=new int[] {2,6,0,8};
int[] b=new int[] {2,6,0,8};

if (a!=b) System.out.println("Error. I was expecting [2,6,0,8]").
```

This comparison would work because a and b reference the same memory address.

```
int[] a=new int[] {2,6,0,8};
int[] b=a;

if (a==b) System.out.println("Your answer is correct.");
```